# CSS brightnesss filter blurs text

Tags: css, css-filters

Using `filter: brightness(x)` on an element leads to the text inside being blurred under Chrome and Firefox. Is this desired behavior? If not, can this be fixed? Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/dye2n0xv/

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(#53a423, #2f6c04);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<button>
Some button label
</button>
```

Just hover the mouse over the button and pay attention to the text. Of course, the example with 100% is stupid, in my use-case I need something like 125%, but I wanted to make sure it's not the browser trying to display a whiter white than white, that's why I went with 100% which should theoretically not alter the element at all.

Comment: Are you sure you linked the correct fiddle?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: No errors here on mac chrome.

Comment: Absolutely sure, I just checked with both browsers. Is there a preferred image storage here on SO? I could post two screenshots.

Comment: Have a look at https://s12.postimg.org/660ud3855/without.png which shows the button without the filter, and https://s12.postimg.org/u8ho7yos9/with.png with filter.

Comment: @smares what is your OS? What happens if you add `contrast(1.1)` and why would use `brightness(100%)` it does nothing.

Comment: @Aziz, did you read my test? Guess not.

"Of course, the example with 100% is stupid, in my use-case I need something like 125%, but I wanted to make sure it's not the browser trying to display a whiter white than white, that's why I went with 100% which should theoretically not alter the element at all." Oh, OS is Windows 7 which is my company's development OS.

Comment: Actually, I see it happen with any filter. `grayscale(100%)`, `contrast(100%)`, all of them mess with the sharpness of the text. I even tried playing with various `-webkit-font-smoothing` values including `none` and always get the same outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by nature of filters and the way how they are specified in CSS.

Normally text (on Windows for example) gets rendered using ClearType. Clear type requires non-transparent background. ClearType uses sub-pixel antialising so you see the text more clear cut. In ClearType each addressable pixel renders de facto three "dots".

When you apply filter, the engine is forced to create a bitmap for the element, render content on it, apply filter to its pixels and render final bitmap as a whole. Text gets rendered on such bitmap with gray scale antialiasing. That method does not use sub-pixel AA so you see the text more blurry.

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType

If you think a bit on illustrations there then you will understand why ClearType cannot be used with [color] filters applied.

Comment: Just to let you guys know, I tested this at home on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox and the problem does not occur. On my gaming PC running Windows 8.1 and Chrome and Firefox, it does occur. So it seems it's something related to ClearType indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It’s normal because when you apply a CSS filter on an element, all its children will be affected.

What you need to do is to separate the text from the background, and make the filter only on the background.

this is an example

```
<button>
<span class="background"></span>
<span class="text">Some button label</span>
</button>
```

and CSS

```
button {
border: none;
background:none;
}

.text {
border: none;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
}

.background:hover {
filter: brightness(125%);
}

.background {
width:140px;
height:40px;
background: linear-gradient(#53a423, #2f6c04);  
z-index:0;
position:absolute;
}
```

Note: you will need a javascript function to make the filter work on hover over text because of z-index

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is quite simple code, I am assuming this is normal behavior, and no error of yours. If you do not want this effect, the easiest thing to do is simply change the background of the button to a lighter color on hover. I'm sure it has something to do with the `filter` rendering system that makes the text blurry, probably because `brightness` might take the button as an image, and ignore that the text inside of the button is text, and treat it as just basic color values, shifting them around and thus, blurring them